# How to get events info of requested Room ID in payload using calendar getSchedule API through App access token

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to get events info of Teams Rooms by Room ID from Calendar getSchedule API using service principal or App access token.

In my Application i need information of events like subject, location, start time and end time at particular date.

so i called api POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id/UserPrincipalName}/calendar/getSchedule](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser_id/UserPrincipalName%7D/calendar/getSchedule) Where UserPrincipalName is "ls-meetingroom-gothamcity@test.com"

Then pass request payload.

```
{
    "schedules": ["ls-meetingroom-gothamcity@test.com", "ls-meetingroom-wakanda@test.com"],
    "startTime": {
        "dateTime": "2023-06-27T00:00:00",
        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
    },
    "endTime": {
        "dateTime": "2023-06-27T23:59:59",
        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
    },
    "availabilityViewInterval": 30
}
```

I received response.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.scheduleInformation)",
    "value": [
        {
            "scheduleId": "ls-meetingroom-gothamcity@test.com",
            "availabilityView": "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "scheduleItems": [],
            "workingHours": {
                "daysOfWeek": [
                    "monday",
                    "tuesday",
                    "wednesday",
                    "thursday",
                    "friday"
                ],
                "startTime": "08:00:00.0000000",
                "endTime": "17:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": {
                    "name": "Pacific Standard Time"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "scheduleId": "ls-meetingroom-wakanda@test.com",
            "availabilityView": "000000000000000000000000000202002020002000000000",
            "scheduleItems": [
                {
                    "status": "busy",
                    "start": {
                        "dateTime": "2023-06-27T13:30:00.0000000",
                        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "dateTime": "2023-06-27T14:00:00.0000000",
                        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "status": "busy",
                    "start": {
                        "dateTime": "2023-06-27T14:30:00.0000000",
                        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "dateTime": "2023-06-27T15:00:00.0000000",
                        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "workingHours": {
                "daysOfWeek": [
                    "monday",
                    "tuesday",
                    "wednesday",
                    "thursday",
                    "friday"
                ],
                "startTime": "08:00:00.0000000",
                "endTime": "17:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": {
                    "name": "Pacific Standard Time"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But my problems are

I am not able to get response of events info like Subject, location except start time, end time and status from given payload "schedules": ["ls-meetingroom-gothamcity@test.com", "ls-meetingroom-wakanda@test.com"].

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leXMZ.png)

Thank You!

Expected : Response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.scheduleInformation)",
    "value": [
        {
            "scheduleId": "ls-meetingroom-gothamcity@test.com",
            "availabilityView": "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "scheduleItems": [
                {
                    "isPrivate": false,
                    "status": "busy",
                    "subject": "Test Meeting 27 Jun 11:30 start for 30 min",
                    "location": "Wakanda",
                    "isMeeting": true,
                    "isRecurring": false,
                    "isException": false,
                    "isReminderSet": false,
                    "start": {
                        "dateTime": "2023-06-27T11:30:00.0000000",
                        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "dateTime": "2023-06-27T12:00:00.0000000",
                        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "scheduleId": "ls-meetingroom-wakanda@test.com",
            "availabilityView": "000000000000000000000000000202002020002000000000",
            "scheduleItems": [
                {
                    "isPrivate": false,
                    "status": "busy",
                    "subject": "Test Meeting 27 Jun 13:30 start for 30 min",
                    "location": "Wakanda",
                    "isMeeting": true,
                    "isRecurring": false,
                    "isException": false,
                    "isReminderSet": false,
                    "start": {
                        "dateTime": "2023-06-27T13:30:00.0000000",
                        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "dateTime": "2023-06-27T14:00:00.0000000",
                        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> so i called api POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id/UserPrincipalName}/calendar/getSchedule](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser_id/UserPrincipalName%7D/calendar/getSchedule) Where UserPrincipalName is "ls-meetingroom-gothamcity@test.com"

When you make this call because your using ls-meetingroom-gothamcity@test.com as the userId you will be impersonating this account. This means the permission that this account has to the other mailboxes becomes relevant for you to get subject information you need "ls-meetingroom-gothamcity@test.com" (or whatever account you going to use) to have either limited details or reviewer permission to that other calendars you want to query. By default it would only have freebusy permission which is why you just get the time details. This issue is covered in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-free-busy-schedule#event-data-returned

In the result you posted "ls-meetingroom-gothamcity@test.com" has no appointments in the range where "ls-meetingroom-wakanda@test.com" does have meetings if you swap to using the id in the request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ls-meetingroom-wakanda@test.com/calendar/getSchedule you should see the subject details for ls-meetingroom-wakanda@test.com as the account you then impersonating has rights to it own mailbox.

The other thing you can do is if you can't change the permissions (or it's too much administrative overhead on a ongoing basis) is just query the calendar endpoint for each user which your app permissions would allow. Your application permissions if they are readwrite would also allow you to add/check the permission to the target mailboxes in question as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendarpermission-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http . The minimum you would need would be         "limitedRead","read", to get the details as the impersonating user.